# How to print a result in bold font in Times New Roman?

Tags: siunitx

Once `mathptmx` for Times New Roman is loaded, `siunitx` can't print results in **bold** anymore. How can this be solved?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% required (Times New Roman)
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}, group-minimum-digits = 4,
  detect-weight = true, detect-inline-weight = text}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand*{\eval}[1]{$\num{\fp_eval:n {#1}}$}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\res}{1000}
The costs are \$\eval{\res}/y (normal font) and {\bfseries \$\eval{\res}/y} (bold). % this would be bold without Times New Roman
\end{document}
```

Comment: `mathptmx` doesn't contain boldface fonts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. What does `\textbf{}` do then and can this be used to "locally" switch to a font which has boldface and thus `detect-weight` would work?

Comment: Off-topic: I wouldn't place the argument of `\eval` in math mode. Hence, I'd write `\newcommand*{\eval}[1]{\num{\fp_eval:n {#1}}}` or, better yet (as explained in the addendum to the answer shown below) `\newcommand*{\eval}[1]{\num[mode=text]{\fp_eval:n {#1}}}`. The latter forces `siunitx` to obey the prevailing text font settings (which may, but don't have to, include `\bfseries`).

Comment: You need to use other font family for math, for example `newtxmath`. And sorry, `mathptmx` has boldface math font which work in math mode, for example as `$\mathbf{1000}$` but not on your desired way.

Comment: @Zarko -- There are presumably several valid reasons for preferring to use `newtxmath` (and `newtxtext` too, right?) over `mathptmx`. However, since the OP's issue continues to be present if `\usepackage{mathptmx}` is replaced with `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}`, I wouldn't bring up differences between Times Roman math font packages in the present context.

Comment: @Mico, you are right. However, now I'm wondering, where is difference between  `mathptmx` and `newtxmath`, that the second one `siunitx` can recognize their boldface  version at the first one not (and for this need the help of `mode=text`). And +1 for your answer :-)

Comment: @Zarko - Many thanks for the upvote. :-) I'm not sure I follow your claim that `siunitx` is able to "recognize the boldface version" with `newtxmath` but not with `mathptmx`. To me, the only difference between `mathptmx` and `newtxmath` in the OP's code is that the comma which serves as the thousands-separator is rendered in **bold** if `newtxmath` is loaded, wheres that comma is non-bold with `mathptmx`. The `1` and `0` numerals do not seem to be affected by switching between `mathptmx` and `newtxtext/newtxmath`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may achieve your objective by adding the option `detect-weight` option to `\num` inside the `\eval` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}, group-minimum-digits = 4}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand*{\eval}[1]{\num[detect-weight]{\fp_eval:n {#1}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\res}{1000}
The costs are \textbf{\$\eval{\res}/year}.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, posted after the OP provided the piece of information that the `mathptmx` package is in use. (This detail wasn't mentioned in the initial version of the posting, upon which I based the answer shown above.) My suggestion: add the option `mode=text` to the argument of `\num`.

Comment: Hi Mico, thanks for your answer. I just found the same and then realized it didn't work in my non-minimal example. I found out that this is due to Times New Roman which is a requirement for this case (unfortunately). Do you know how this can be achieved?

Comment: @MariusHofert - Please see the addendum I posted a short while ago.

Comment: Excellent, thanks, works.